# Script injected to Chrome using extension and content script is not execute first

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I need a script to execute before any other scripts on page, and so using Chrome extension to inject it in to every page. The script did injected before the head element but somehow it only run first when I use Control + F5, otherwise if I only use F5 or browse the page it will run last, even though it still in the same position when I check by developer tool.

My manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My test 15",
  "version": "1.0.0",  
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["loadscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
   "web_accessible_resources": ["test.js"]
}
```

My loadscript.js

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('test.js');
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

Script in test.js

```
window.alert("hello from test.js");
```

Script in the page

```
window.alert("hello from page");
```

When I browse to the page on localhost, everything look to be load correctly as

```
<html>
<script src="chrome-extension://idjbemfgdjiggddofddpkcoccihmnefa/test.js"></script>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>window.alert("hello from page");</script>
</body>
```

The thing is script in test.js only run first if I press control + f5. If I browse to the page even in the first time or using f5 only, then the script in test.js will run last. Can anyone has a solution for this? thank you.

Comment: See https://crbug.com/634381. Script elements with src attribute are enqueued along with the page's own scripts and their load order is nondeterminstic. To ensure synchronous execution assign a literal string to the `textContent` property of the script element.

Comment: It work. @wOxxOm: I have read a few of your answers already. They must save thousand working hours for everyone. Thanks.